# Can I commit debug version to App store?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

Only Release version, or debug version is also accepted?
I had committed a debug version. So I wondered.
Edit scheme - Debug/Release

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html
It said :

```
Reviewing the Archive Scheme Settings
If necessary, review the Archive scheme settings to ensure that you don’t archive a debug version of your app.
```

Comment: I think the fact that Xcode even makes separate release and debug builds should make the answer pretty obvious...

Comment: ?Does anyone commit debug version scheme successfully to app store? Should I reject my app now and recommit a release version?